# Multiple Context Menus on single html element

Tags: javascript, html, contextmenu

I want to have two different context menues on single element td right click. 
My html code is like.

```
<td context-menu="otherMenuOptions"  model="val['origin']['ip']"><span ng-show="!val['origin']['ip']">-</span> <a href="#/app/showIps/{{val['destination']['countryCode']}}/ip/{{val['origin']['ip']}}" target="_blank">{{val['origin']['ip']}} </a> </td>
```

My jscode is as:
context menu 1:

```
     $scope.otherMenuOptions = [
        ['Add into Search', function ($itemScope, $event, color) {
             if($scope.demo['tags'] != undefined){
                  if($scope.demo['tags'].length >= 1){

                    var check = _.filter($scope.demo['tags'], function(num){
                            return num['text'] === color; });
                    //console.log(check);       
                    if(check.length == 0){
                        $scope.demo['tags'].push({text:color});
                    }else{
                        //alert("match");
                    }
                  }else { $scope.demo['tags'] = [];
                          $scope.demo['tags'].push({text:color});
                        }                   
            }else{

                $scope.demo['tags'] = [];
                $scope.demo['tags'].push(color);

            }
        }]
    ];
```

Context menu 2:

```
$scope.whiteList=[  ['Add to white list', function ($itemScope, $event, ip) {
    whiteList($itemScope.$parent.item.data.Ip);
}]]
```

I want to execute two context menus on same click.

Comment: If you are using this: https://github.com/Templarian/ui.bootstrap.contextMenu/blob/master/contextMenu.js#L217-L227 ... I don't think what you are asking to do is possible. There are ways to do it, but it would require rewriting the `ui.bootstrap` directive for `contextMenu`.

Comment: Am using contextmenu.js